# Get custom menu item to appear with every instance of application

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to create a custom menu item so that it is present every time you open the application? For example, every time I open a new google doc the menu item appears so that I can run my script in any and every document rather than only in the original "container" document.

Comment: Yes, if you create an add-on otherwise you'll have to copy and paste the code to each doc. If you have a G Suite account you'll be able to publish an add-on to your domain without having to go through the full procedure.

Comment: Currently, I don’t believe that is possible.

Comment: You can use an addon but you still have to add the addon after each document creation.